# get id rather then class tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I found this [HowTo](http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/how-to-make-your-site-multilingual-using-xml-and-jquery/) and modified the script a bit, but I would like to select id tags rather than class tags.
In other words:
Right now it works for class="title", and I like it to work with id="title"

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() {
    var language = '{{@LANGUAGE}}';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'vps.xml',
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('translation').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var text = $(this).find(language).text();
                $("." + id).html(text);
                $("." + id).addClass(id + '_' + language);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `.` to a hashtag `#`

```
$("#" + id)
```